# SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Am using React router and once I try to test the component that is using the with-router high order function I get an error that, everything else is working out well and therefore cannot rule that my configuration might be having a problem,

> import React from "react";
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Here is the code, am trying to test the component downloadEmployeep9, below is the test and the code for the component.

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import downloadEmployeeP9 from 
"../../../components/payroll/payslips/downloadEmployeeP9";

describe("should test download employee p9", () => {
  it("should test employee has p9 ", () => {
     const wrapper = shallow(<downloadEmployeeP9 />);
   });
});
```

**Component code**

```
import withRouter from "react-router/es/withRouter";

export default withStyles(styles)(
    withRouter(
       connect(mapStateToProps, {
   })(DownloadEmployeeP9)
 )
);
```

Comment: Show us the place where you wrote the above statement.

Comment: @Novak254 some more insight or the code written by you?

Comment: @PrakharMittal have made an edit